# How to create boolean variable to calculate a sum for integer programming

Tags: propositional-calculus, integer-programming

This is done in order to calculate the population at risks with the construction of a site.

> A company wants to select $p$ locations among a set of $m$ possible sites for constructing polluting plants in a contemporary world. The $m$ candidate sites are located on a territory containing different cities. We have:
>
> - $d_{ij}$ the distance between city $i$ and site $j$
> - $P_i$ the population (in thousand of inhabitants) of city $i$
>
> I imagined experts that thought that a city was threatened if there was a polluting plant located less than 2 km from it.
>
> There are two different factions :
>
> 1. The authorities' point of view that wants to minimize nuisance. They
>      want to minimize the number of inhabitants threatened by the $p$
>      selected plants.
> 2. The company point of view that wants to minimize the transportation costs. 
>      They take into account the volume of goods transported between the $p$ plants and the $n$ clients. The transportation cost from a plant $j$ to a client city $i$ is $1.5€$ per kilometer and per $m^3$ of transported good. The annual demand of city $i$ is $V_i$ (in $m^3$). It will be needed to transform the first model so that :
>
>    - At most 5% of the population of $n$ cities are threatened (constraint imposed by the authorities).
>    - The demand of a city is delivered by a single plant
>    - The company minimizes its total transportation cost

Generally speaking I thought developing a variable $t_i$ in order to create another one $s_j$: how many people are subject to a risk with the construction of a site $j$.

How to calculate the variable $s_j$, the number of people risking something with the construction of the site $j$ ?

#### My attempt

I thought about

\begin{cases}
\min & \sum_j\sum_i s_{ij}\\
&s_{ij}=b_{ij}\times P_i\mbox{ number of people of city $i$ endangered by site $j$}\\
&d_{ij}\times t_{ij}\le2  \mbox{ constraint over the distance to flag an endangered population}\\
&\sum_i b_i= \mbox{ number of sites we want}\\
b_i \in \{0,1\}
\end{cases}

With the additional variables :

- $s_{ij}$ the population endangered in city $i$ by site $j$
- $b_{ij}$ a boolean variable telling me if city $i$ is threatened by
  site $j$.

We want to minimize the sum of $s_{ij}$, the number of people endangered.
I thought about creating a variable $b_i$, standing for "take into account population $i$" with the following test :

$$d_{ij}\times t_{ij}\le2$$

\begin{cases}
b_i = 0 \mbox{ if we don't have to take the population of city $i$ into account}\\
b_i = 1 \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}

It is okay but I don't think we can generalize it :

Actually, if $d_{ij}=2\Rightarrow t_i = 1 \mbox{ or $0$}$. I want it to be 0 compulsorily.

Answer (score 1):

You could precalculate an incidence matrix $a_{i,j}\in \{0,1\}$ where $a_{i,j}=1$ indicates city $i$ is at risk when construction is done at site $j$. Assume we model construction at $j$ by a binary decision variable $x_j=1$. If there is only one possible $x_j=1$ we can simply use:

$$
t_i = \sum_j a_{i,j} x_j
$$

If multiple $x_j$ can be chosen, we can do

$$
n \cdot t_i \ge \sum_j a_{i,j} x_j
$$
where $n$ is the maximum number of sites that can be selected. (Here I assume there is a cost involved with $t_i$ so indirectly we minimize it; this approach also works if we have an upper limit on $t_i$ e.g. $\sum_i b_i t_i \le K$). The last constraint can also be disaggregated as:
$$
   t_i \ge x_j \>\> \forall (i,j)|a_{i,j}=1 
$$

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! yet, you don't take the distance $d_{ij}$ into account here, don't you ?

Comment: Yes. Use the distance to populate the a matrix. (Ahead of optimization).